# How to plot multiple plot matrices side-by-side on a device?

Tags: r

I'm trying to save 2 plot matrices side-by-side to a png device (using `pairs` or `GGally::ggpairs`), but only the last plot is shown. When I save to a pdf I can see that the 2 plots are going to different pages.

```
png("test.png", 12, 6, units = "in", res = 300)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
pairs(iris)
pairs(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

I also tried to adjust the plot area of each plot using `par(pin=c(,))` to make them much smaller than device's area, but that doesn't help.

Comment: `pairs` does its own call to `par` that overwrites your call, since it makes so many plots. I don't know of a way besides just combining them manually

Comment: @SeñorO That won't work as those don't play with `par`.

Comment: Oh, I should have thought of that. What do you suggest? I tried `layout()` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Creating two images and putting them together in paint.

Comment: Or instead of using 'pairs', create your own function that plots the relevant variables and then you can use `par` on those.